# how to remove the lines in captcha

Tags: ocr, captcha

I have a simple captcha,I want to recognize the picture.
the picture is like:
[image]

I want to use the tesseract.  http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

but the tesseract only can use on the clear picture.

so I should preprocess the pic.

the preprocess code is:

```
im = Image.open('test.png')
# text = image_to_string(im)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(4)
img = img.convert("RGBA")
width,height = im.size
# pixdata = img.load()
for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
        if im.getpixel((x,y)) != (0,0,0):
            im.putpixel((x,y),(255,255,255) )

for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
        if y<2 or y>(img.size[1]-3):
            continue
        if im.getpixel((x, y))[0]==255 and im.getpixel((x, y+2))[0]==0 and im.getpixel((x, y-1))[0]==0:
            im.putpixel((x, y),(0,0,0))
     #    else:
     #      continue
list(im.getdata())
im.show()
```

after the process,the pic is like:
[image]

so I failed. can anyone give me some tips?
I know how to remove the line if the line is a pixel width,but the line here is not consistent.